# Write in MSMQ file an XML encoded in UTF8 With Bom

Tags: xml, vb.net, utf-8, msmq

I’m trying to write in a msmq file an UTF8 with Bom xml , so I created my own formatter like this (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310683)

But in result i have an UTF8 without Bom XML
So i tried this :
Public Sub Write(message As System.Messaging.Message, obj As Object) Implements System.Messaging.IMessageFormatter.Write

```
    Dim utf8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(True)
    Dim stm As Stream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stm, utf8)
    writer.Write(obj.ToString())
    message.BodyStream = stm
```

End Sub

it works but it cuts my xml and I don’t close the writer !!

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the StreamWriter has buffered data which is [not being flushed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
…    
writer.Write(obj.ToString())
writer.Flush();
message.BodyStream = stm
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I tried this but its return Cannot access a closed Stream exception

Comment: Ah OK. In that case just flushing the StreamWriter after the Write call should work.